# Lorentz force within a flux tube

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, classical-electrodynamics

I know the formula for the Lorenz force exerted on a point charge $q$ moving with velocity $\vec{v}$ is given by $\vec{F} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$. Now consider the flux tube with cross section $S$ and length $d\ell$, particle density $\mathcal{N}$ and drift velocity $\vec{v}_d$, as illustrated in the picture below.
[image: Flux tube]

Now, I do not understand how to go from the given formula above to this formula for the total Lorenz forces on the particles:

$$d\vec{F} = \mathcal{N}qd\ell S \vec{v}_d \times \vec{B} = I\vec{d}\ell \times \vec{B}$$

Furthermore, I am missing out on some extra mathematical steps in the statement above. Can anyone write this a little bit out so that it becomes clear to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part is the electrical current density, which is
$$ \vec{j} = \rho\vec{v}_d = q{\cal N}\vec{v}_d.$$
Then
$$ \vec{j}\times\vec{B} = {\cal N}\cdot q\vec{v}_d\times\vec{B}.$$
Integration over the cross-sectional area of the current carrying tube leads to
$$ \vec{I}\times\vec{B} = {\cal N}S\cdot q\vec{v}_d\times\vec{B}.$$
Multiplying with the length $d\ell$ of an infinitesimal section of the tube results in
$$ \vec{I}\times\vec{B}d\ell = {\cal N}Sd\ell\cdot q\vec{v}_d\times\vec{B}.$$
The expression ${\cal N}Sd\ell$ is the number of charges $q$ within the infinitesimal volume $Sd\ell$ of the tube, while $q\vec{v}_d\times\vec{B}$ is the force on each of the individual charges. The expression on the right hand side is therefore the total force acting on all the charges (and thereby on the whole tube section of length $d\ell$, such that we can write
$$ d\vec{F} = \vec{I}\times\vec{B}d\ell = {\cal N}Sd\ell\cdot q\vec{v}_d\times\vec{B}. $$

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing both this mathematical and physical insight!